# I feel I'm not getting paid completely. Do these numbers add up?

Tags: united-states, payment, employment, texas

This is my following pay statement for a 2-week period:

[image: This is my pay statement for a 2 week period]

[image: This is my time card]

[image: Hours from my app from work]

I worked in total 183 hours in a 2 week interval, my questions is why am I getting paid to little for overtime? 183-80(hours of regular)= 103 hours of overtime, but some of the rates are normal pay.The app from the company states 183 hours, and this pay statement is 142.6, so I don't know what the difference is.  Who could I go with to see if i'm getting screwed? This is in Texas

Comment: depends on their OT policy, your state's OT policy and even then it is sometimes made dependent on how much of that you did in one continuous chunk, so technically if you do 8 hours and they give you 1-2 two hours off the clock and you go back, you don't qualify for OT - it is as simple as that sometimes to "screw you" so you need to find out what the law is and make sure your employer is not doing an end run on it, like when they make you just 2 hours shy of full time so they don't have to give you benefits, even if they make you work more

Comment: I see 142.6 hours.

Comment: Yeah that's is what I just realized, since app from the company states 183 hours, and this pay statement is 142.6, so I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: The 'weekend diff' is the difference, if you don't include that you get 142.6. It looks like weekend hours get a uniform bump regardless of whether they are overtime or regular, or something, but your time sheet indicates that's the disparity.

Comment: Looks like you get paid a nominal sum ($1.8999/hr) for being on call for 40 hours, but not actually at work

Comment: So what does that mean, that everything is fine? Shouldn't I still be getting around 60 hours of overtime?  Since the payment states only 37.90 in a overtime rate, and the rest are normal rates

Comment: Disregard my last comment, @HartCO has got it...your weekend time is getting double counted in the 183 number.

Comment: It looks like the app adds those weekend on call or whatever they are to your total hours, so it's just a flaw in how they report it, but it doesn't appear anything is wrong.  I think in total you got 54.6 hours of overtime, 3 different 'ot' sections. You would expect ~62 hours of OT total, but there was a holiday in play, and those typically don't count, so 54 makes sense.

Comment: but If I got 54.6 hours of overtime, why am I only getting paid 37 hours with an overtime rate, and the rest a normal rate?

Comment: See the other lines, 'evening ot' and 'night ot' You have 37.9 in 'overtime' plus 16.23 in 'evening ot' and 0.47 in 'night ot', for a total of 54.6 overtime hours

Comment: Do you actually track the hours you work? You should be comparing your actual schedule [add up all the hours you worked, every day, over the period each pay stub covers] to the pay stub and then the bank statement. You are missing a step here if you aren't manually tallying the actual numbers you worked. For all we know, you worked 200 hours! Only you know what you actually worked, so you should track it to keep your employer honest.

Comment: The question is why evening ot and night ot normal rates?

Comment: Actually, the line item doesn't make sense, if you divide the 366 for evening ot by the 16.23 hours, you get a rate of 22.55

Comment: Wow you work too much

Comment: I'm confused why **you** don't know how much you worked. If I got a paystub showing I worked 100 hours in a week I know I only worked 40, I wouldn't be confused as to why the paystub would be wrong in its calculation of overtime.

Comment: I'm confused on how they have the different rates, and the hours, but I already got it resolved thanks.

Comment: @Killercamin and the resolution was?

Comment: The difference in hours was because of the weekend differentials, but the rate of the hours is still being discussed with HR, but most likely they will say "it's company policy"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The statement suggests that you worked 114.13 hours this pay period, not the amount you suggest (68.23+37.9+8).  So that could be the discrepancy in yours and your employer's calculation.

It looks as if your overtime computation is slightly more than double time.  That is pretty generous.  Additionally there are other contributors that add to income as far as night and weekend differential.

Additional info:  If you add up all the numbers in the second column, I come up with 182.57, close to the 183 you are claiming.   However, differential calculation typically does not work like that.  For example, if you work one hour on the weekend, you would have one hour on the first line, and one hour on the weekend differential line.  Your gross pay would be $16.04 (14.14+1.90).

So the question is did you actually work 183 hours in two weeks?  That is a whole lot.  That is over 13 hours per day with no days off.

Comment: Let me edit something, I added my time card

Comment: From your time card I got 142.59.

Comment: Let me add the total hours the app from the company is stating

Comment: In the end I think you need to sit down with your HR/payroll department and figure out the discrepancy.   You certainly work pretty damn hard, and my hat is off to you.

Comment: Thank you, so the pay statement looks fine then? Let's assume i did only work for 142 hours, wouldn't that still be 60 hours of overtime? Why does my pay statement give me 38 of overtime pay, while the rest of the hours are simply normal rate?

Comment: @Killercamin I would not say everything looks fine.  At the very least the app is goofed up, and there could be other things.

Comment: What would you suggest me doing? Talking with HR, and if they can't come up with an explanation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66168/discussion-between-pete-b-and-killercamin).

Answer (score 16):

It looks like there are errors, but I believe your total pay is accurate.

The first error is that the app seems to double-count weekend hours. You worked 39.96 weekend hours, and they pay a little extra for weekend hours and record them on a separate line, they shouldn't be added to the total hours since they are already reflected in the other categories. This explains why the timesheet shows 142.6 hours and the app shows 182.6 hours.

The second error seems to be that they show the 'evening ot' rate as $14.14, but actually pay $22.56/hour for those ($366.15 for 16.23 evening ot hours). The shown rate is accurate for all other lines, and the pay on each line adds up to the total gross pay reflected in the app.

The line item totals coincide with what the app says for total pay, so it seems like the pay is working properly, but that they have a couple errors in how they are displaying the data.

It's not the clearest way to present the information, they seem to use 'diff' inconsistently and have presentation issues, so it wouldn't hurt to get some clarification, but there's nothing that suggests you aren't getting paid what you should (so long as you agree with the hours recorded).

Comment: I've also worked out that Evening hours are 5pm to 10pm and Night hours are 10pm to 7am.  Aside from the Evening OT rate, everything seems to check out in the pay stub numbers.